# How to "Hello World" programmatically on remote machine in elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

Objective: Print "hello world" on the remote machine.

I want to spawn a process from my computer and print "Hello World" (call Sample.hello) on remote machine. There are ways to connect nodes on a different machine as mentioned [here](http://benjamintan.io/blog/2014/05/25/connecting-elixir-nodes-on-the-same-lan/). But this is using iex commands.
How to print "Hello World" **programmatically** on remote machine?

```
defmodule Sample do


  def hello do
    IO.puts "Hello World"
  end

  def main(args \\ []) do

    # IP address of remote server from command line argument.

    {_, input, _} = OptionParser.parse(args, switches: [])
    ipaddress = List.to_string(input)

    """
      1. spawn new process
      2. print hello world on remote machine - Call Sample.hello
    """
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "start remote server"? Are you trying to turn a physical (or virtual) computer on? Are you trying to start an Erlang/Elixir node? Something else?

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect representation. I just want to execute hello world program on remote machine.

Comment: Could you use something like Erlang [rpc][1] module?
   [1]: http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html

Answer (score 0):

On REMOTE machine start the VM

```
$ iex --sname "node@192.168.0.202" --cookie mycookie
```

On LOCAL machine start the VM

```
$ iex --sname "node@192.168.0.201" --cookie mycookie
```

In the local elixir terminal

```
Node.connect :"node@192.168.0.202"
Main.main(  :"node@192.168.0.202" )
```

Where you have already compiled the source

```
defmodule Sample do
  def loop  do
    receive do
      {:message, msg} -> IO.puts message
    end   
    loop()
  end
end

defmodule Main do
  def main( node ) do
    pid = Node.spawn( node, Sample, :loop, [ ] );
    send pid, {:message, "Hello world"};
  end
end
```

I haven't run this but it should work as long as you customize the ip address/names

Comment: Are you sure that **Remote** node will know about `Sample` module? Won't you have undefined error?  And you don't need two machines to test it, you could run two VM on one machine, just name them `node1@localhost` and `node2@localhost`. I will work in the same way.

Comment: As far as I can remember you don't need to place the Module in remote VM - I think it gets 'sent there' by `Node.spawn` - since I don't have 2 machines here at the moment I cannot easily check for you.

Comment: I want to connect nodes programmatically and not from terminal. I am trying to do Node.spawn( node, Sample, :loop, [ ] ); But it throws following  error  ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: :distribution_not_started
    (kernel) auth.erl:120: :auth.set_cookie/2       
how to set cookie (Node.set_cookie/2) before spawning ?

Comment: Oh I forgot you need to start each VM with the same authentication cookie. See my updated answer above - where it says `--cookie mycookie`

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this. Here is an example.

**Remote setup**

`mix new foo`

Edit `foo/lib/foo.ex` to look like this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def connect do
    Node.start(:foo@foohostname, :shortnames)
    Node.set_cookie(:foo@foohostname, :shh_dont_tell)
  end

  def hello do
    IO.puts :world
  end
end
```

Be sure to put your hostname on your local network in place of `foohostname`.

Next, start it up. You mentioned you want to avoid iex, so you can start your application however you prefer. You could create a mix script to start it and connect, for example. But since that is a digression from the topic at hand, I will start it with iex:

`iex -S mix`

Followed by:

`iex(1)> Foo.connect`

**Local setup**

`mix new bar`

In `bar/lib/bar.ex`:

```
defmodule Bar do
  def connect do
    Node.start(:bar@barhostname, :shortnames)
    Node.set_cookie(:bar@barhostname, :shh_dont_tell)
    Node.connect(:foo@foohostname)
  end
end
```

Remember to substitute the hostname for bar into `barhostname` and likewise for foo.

Now, you have a programmatic means to connect your nodes. You can access the other Foo node anywhere in the Bar application.

Let's use iex again for an example. Follow along at the commandline:

`iex -S mix`

```
iex(1)> Bar.connect
#PID<16393.795.0>
```

```
iex(bar@barhostname)> Node.spawn_link :foo@foohostname, fn -> Foo.hello end
world
#PID<16393.795.0>
```

Note that connecting the nodes is not necessary for spawning one-off function calls like this, so in this example you could choose not to include the `Node.connect` line, but it is necessary for more sophisticated node management.

Answer (score -1):

@GavinBrelstaff answer is ok but can be simplified to:

In one terminal:

```
$ iex --sname node1@localhost
```

In another terminal:

```
$ iex --sname node2@localhost
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.5.1) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(node2@localhost)1> Node.spawn(:"node1@localhost", fn -> IO.puts("Run on #{Node.self}") end)
#PID<9960.95.0>
Run on node1@localhost
```

You can see the function was run on node1. Note that the IO.puts output **is redirected** to the console on node2 so it's not printed out on node1 (this could be the source of your confusion maybe?).

Comment: This solution was the best for me. OSX doesn't like me just naming my node as foo, and then connecting to it from another node. I have to add the @localhost, otherwise it never connects.